# Dockerfile with React app not working with "create-react-app ." command in RUN section

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a Dockerfile with a node and install ReactJS there:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN npm install -g create-react-app
RUN create-react-app .
CMD npm start
```

During the build, the following errors occur, and the corresponding files do not appear in the volume:

```
Creating a new React app in /home/node/app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.2.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.2.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 6 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.1.1
├─ react-dom@17.0.1
├─ react-scripts@4.0.1
└─ react@17.0.1
info All dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.1.1
├─ react-dev-utils@11.0.1
├─ react-dom@17.0.1
├─ react-scripts@4.0.1
├─ react@17.0.1
└─ scheduler@0.20.1
Done in 49.74s.

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using yarnpkg...
yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.2.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.2.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.6.2" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 17 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @testing-library/jest-dom@5.11.9
├─ @testing-library/react@11.2.3
├─ @testing-library/user-event@12.6.2
├─ react-dom@17.0.1
├─ react@17.0.1
└─ web-vitals@0.2.4
info All dependencies
├─ @testing-library/dom@7.29.4
├─ @testing-library/jest-dom@5.11.9
├─ @testing-library/react@11.2.3
├─ @testing-library/user-event@12.6.2
├─ @types/aria-query@4.2.1
├─ @types/jest@26.0.20
├─ @types/testing-library__jest-dom@5.9.5
├─ css.escape@1.5.1
├─ css@3.0.0
├─ dom-accessibility-api@0.5.4
├─ lz-string@1.4.4
├─ min-indent@1.0.1
├─ react-dom@17.0.1
├─ react@17.0.1
├─ redent@3.0.0
├─ strip-indent@3.0.0
└─ web-vitals@0.2.4
Done in 10.61s.
Removing template package using yarnpkg...

yarn remove v1.22.5
[1/2] Removing module cra-template...
[2/2] Regenerating lockfile and installing missing dependencies...
info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.2.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.2.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.6.2" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
success Uninstalled packages.
Done in 10.09s.
Git commit not created Error: Command failed: git commit -m "Initialize project using Create React App"
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:682:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:719:15)
    at tryGitCommit (/home/node/app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/init.js:62:5)
    at module.exports (/home/node/app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/init.js:352:25)
    at [eval]:3:14
    at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:134:12)
    at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:311:38)
    at node:internal/process/execution:77:19
    at [eval]-wrapper:6:22
    at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:76:60) {
  status: 128,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 153,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
Removing .git directory...

Success! Created app at /home/node/app
```

But if I transfer the command `create-react-app .` to the CMD section, the Dockerfile will be successfully built, but the next time the docker-container is started, there will be an error, since CMD executes the command every time it starts and tries to install the React.
How to make a container with Node correctly and install a ReactJS there?

Comment: I can't imagine this is what you want. Typically you would run create-web-app directly in your dev environment, then edit it as desired (develop the actual app you want), and only then build a docker image from the result.

Comment: You mention a volume; how does that come into things?  (`docker build` can never create files in a volume or directly on the host; if you mount a volume or host directory into a container then the contents of that volume always hide what's in the image, excepting one special case involving empty Docker named volumes.)

Comment: That is, I just need to build the image of the node and install the react in it using docker exec or something like?